# Making sibling elements take the same width breaks the text in them

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to set the width of the div, and it's content to the width of the paragraph `user-title` in it. This is the HTML and CSS:

```css
.panel {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 #C6C2BF;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem 1rem;
}

.user-title {
  display: flex;
}

.panel>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.panel>div>p {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <p class="user-title">Date 08.03.2018 User: Joe Doe</p>
  <div>
    <p>Some long text in the paragraph that is wider than the title above it</p>
    <p>Another shorter text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

That kind of set up makes the elements take the width of the `user-title` element, but, the text breaks into multiple lines. How can I fix this?
This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mps4ku5x/19/).

Comment: What should be the result?

Comment: What does the width 0 supposed to do? the text goes on 1 line if you remove it

Comment: Your friend is inspect element option on your browser ;)

Comment: The width 0 is set to keep the width of p elements inside of the div, to the same width of the user-title element

Comment: @LinkinTED the wanted result is that the width of all elements is of the width of the user-title element, and that the text looks normal of course. Currently I have as you can see in the fiddle width of all elements set to the width of the user-title element, but the text breaks in the paragraphs inside of the div element.

Comment: Can't you set a width to the box? I mean relying on the title for width will produce different width for each user since their name is different length

Comment: It's achievable with position absolute but then you got other problems to worry about. I think it can be done but it will be a very ugly hack

Comment: I have tried with position absolute, but then I have like you said other problems, specifically with the text being outside of the panel box vertically. I don't won't to set the width of the box as fixed, need to make it auto, I know it will be different width for each user, but that is the specification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm not totally mistaken here, the only way to make that work cross browsers using CSS is to combine `display: inline-block` with `display: table-row`/`display: table-caption`.

Stack snippet

```css
.panel {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 #C6C2BF;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem 1rem;
}

.user-title {
  display: table-row;
}

.panel > div {
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
    <p class="user-title">Date 08.03.2018 User: Joe Doe</p>
    <div>
      <p>Some long text in the paragraph that is wider than the title above it</p>
      <p>Another shorter text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

If you don't care about IE, then use `width: 0; min-width: 100%;` on the `.parent div`.

*Note, I tested this with success on Edge v.16, Firefox v.58 and Chrome v.64, but if it works on Safari I can't say.*

Stack snippet

```css
.panel {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 #C6C2BF;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem 1rem;
}

.panel > div {
  width: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
    <p class="user-title">Date 08.03.2018 User: Joe Doe</p>
    <div>
      <p>Some long text in the paragraph that is wider than the title above it</p>
      <p>Another shorter text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

*Updated*

After some trial-and-error, I got this working on both IE11 and Edge/Firefox/Chrome

Stack snippet

```css
.panel {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 #C6C2BF;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem 1rem;
}

.panel > div {
  width: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  display: flex;           /*  for IE11  */
  flex-wrap: wrap;         /*  for IE11  */
}

.panel > div > p {
  flex: 100%;              /*  for IE11  */
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
    <p class="user-title">Date 08.03.2018 User: Joe Doe</p>
    <div>
      <p>Some long text in the paragraph that is wider than the title above it</p>
      <p>Another shorter text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contain: inline-size;` as a more modern solution.

```css
.panel {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 #C6C2BF;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem 1rem;
}

.panel > div {
  contain: inline-size;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
    <p class="user-title">Date 08.03.2018 User: Joe Doe</p>
    <div>
      <p>Some long text in the paragraph that is wider than the title above it</p>
      <p>Another shorter text</p>
      <p>Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</p>
    </div>
</div>
```